# 32 bit multiplication on 24 bit ALU

Tags: signal-processing, 32-bit, multiplication, 24-bit

I want to port a 32 by 32 bit unsigned multiplication on a 24-bit dsp (it's a Linear Congruential  Generator, so I'm not allowed to truncate, also I don't want to replace yet the current LCG with a 24 bit one). The available data types are 24 and 48 bit ints.

Only the last 32 LSB are needed. Do you know any hacks to implement this in fewer multiplies, masks and shifts than the usual way?

The line looks like this:

```
//val is an int(32 bit)
val = (1664525 * val) + 1013904223;
```

Comment: Don't your compiler have a data type that is double the register size? If not, does it use a 16 or 12-bit data type?

Comment: 1664525 fits in 24 bits, so I don't think there are anyway better than `val = (1664525 * (int48_t)val) + 1013904223;`. You need to do at least 3 24x24 multiplies

Answer (score 0):

An outline would be (in my current compiler style):

```
static uint48_t val = SEED;
...
val = 0xFFFFFFFFUL & ((1664525UL * val) + 1013904223UL);
```

and hopefully the compiler will recognise:

- it can use a multiply and accumulate command
- it only needs a reduced multiply algorithim due to the "high word" of the constant being zero
- the AND could be effected by resetting the upper bits or multiplying a constant and restoring
- ...other stuff depends on your {mystery dsp} target

**Note**
if you scale up the coefficients by 2^16, you can get truncation for free, but due to lack of info
you will have to explore/decide if it is better overall.

Answer (score 0):

(This is more an elaboration why *two* multiplications `24×24`→n, 31<n are enough for 32×32→min(n, 40).)
The question discloses amazingly little about the capabilities to build a method
*32×21→32* `in fewer [24×24] multiplies, masks and shifts than the usual way` on:
`24 and 48 bit ints` & `DSP` (I read *high throughput, non-high latency `24×24→48`*).
**As far as** there indeed *is* a *24×24→48* multiply (or even *24×24+56→56* MAC) *and* one factor is less than 24 bits, the question is pointless, a second multiply being the compelling solution.

The usual composition of a *24<n<48×24<m<48→24<p* multiply from *24×24→48* uses three of the latter; a compiler should know as well as a coder that "the fourth multiply" would yield bits with a significance/position exceeding the combined lengths of the lower parts of the factors.
So, is it possible to generate "the long product" using just a second *24×24→48*?
Let the (bytes of the) factors be *w_xyz* and *W_XYZ*, respectively; the underscores suggesting "the *W*s" being the lower significance bits in the higher significance words/ints if interpreted as 24bit ints. The first *24×24→48* gives the sum of
  **zX**
 y**XzY**
xX**yYzZ**
 x**YyZ

  xZ**, what is needed (fat) is
 w**Z** +
 z**W**.
This can be computed using *one* combined multiplication of
*((w<<16)|(z & 0xff)) × ((W<<16)|(Z & 0xff))*. (Never mind the 17th bit of wZ+zW "running" into wW.)
(In the first revision of this answer, I foolishly produced *wZ* and *zW* separately - their sum is wanted in the end, anyway.)
(Annoyingly, this is about all you can do for *24×24→24* as a base operation too - beyond this "combining multiplication", you need *four* instead of one.)

Another angle to explore is choosing a different PRNG.
It *may* have to be >24 bits (tell!).
On a 24 bit machine, [XorShift* (or even XorShift+) 48/32](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift*) seems worth a look.

Comment: (Doesn't *quite* work the way claimed in the 1st revision - working on 32×29; which looks like requiring 32-bit subtraction.) "Obviously", this would be useful if `×` was *way* more costly than "bit operations".